# Apple Watch Program ended with exit code: 0

Tags: xcode, timeout, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I'm using Xcode 8.1, Swift 3.

I'm making a custom watch face for the Apple Watch (For myself).
So i set the watch to always show last app on wake, and after sometime i noticed that it get back to the default watch and my app is closed.

For a week now I'm trying to figure out why the app keep closing.
On Xcode i tried to debug the WatchKit Extension and after some time the console just print: "**Program ended with exit code: 0**" and the app closed again.

I looked on google to check if WatchOs have timeout for apps and didn't find out anything about it.
Also the app is sometimes closed after 5 min and sometimes after 12 h...

The app is never pass the 1.5MB memory.

Any idea what could possibly cause that?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while working on an app.

In my case I'm using SpriteKit scenes which take a lot of memory for rendering to it causes the crashing of the app on watch.

Do check the **memory consumption** of your app. Make it under the bar to test it on the device.

Try to remove the elements which you think of taking a lot of memory. **Use Instruments** to track them.

**NOTE: It will run successfully on Simulator. But on the real apple watch it crashes.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

App will quit after 8 minutes if it is not in the dock, this is explained in WWDC16 videos, other bug might be similar to this:

[Watch App terminates upon deactivation if WKAlert is being shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936749/watch-app-terminates-upon-deactivation-if-wkalert-is-being-shown)